# Installer Crash and "No Bootable Device" with Acer R11

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, acer, usb-installation

On the Acer Aspire R11 I tried running Ubuntu from the USB, it was awesome!!

Touch features and a fully powered laptop !!

But when I wanted to install Ubuntu (I had downloaded 14.04.3) the problems appear :

I chose to erase Windows and make only one partition

- Installation seemed to work fine, everything looking good, BUT:
- On restart, after I remove the USB it shows error "no bootable device"

I went into the BIOS and tried to repeat the installation with :

- secure mode disabled and then with it enabled
- using legacy instead of UEFI, then tried UEFI again
- F12 boot was already enabled from the start
- In order to disable the secure boot mode, I had to create a boot admin password, so I have done.

In all these permutations, I tried to install Ubuntu from the USB but:

Each time the installation is aborted about half way through downloading files (i.e. after the "who are you?" screen)

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found that I had to  install Ubuntu from a DVD, not a USB.

That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It will work from usb if you add the `acpi=off` option to the boot command, both before and after the `--` delimiter.

To get the command line in legacy mode: press the "down" key when the keyboard icon comes up, select English. Make sure "Try Ubuntu Before Installing" is highighted then press F6. Don't select anything in the menu that comes up, press esc. The boot command will display below. Add `acpi=off` before and after `--` then press enter.

To get the command line in UEFI mode: with "Try Ubuntu Before Installing" is highlighted in GRUB, press `e`. Again, add `acpi=off` before and after `--`, then press F10.

Alternately, boot to another OS and/or on another PC, then plug in the USB stick and use an editor that will allow you to save in UNIX format then:

For UEFI mode: Edit `\boot\grub\grub.cfg` to add `acpi=off` before and after `--` where it appears and save.

For Legacy mode: Edit `isolinux\txt.cfg` to add `acpi=off` before and after `--` where it appears and save.